# Is There an Opensource Manual Calculation of AES-128 bit?

Tags: aes

Is There an Opensource Manual Calculation of AES-128 bit as in [Cronos](http://www.cronos.est.pr/AESencrypt.php)

I have to learn calculations manually.

Comment: Note that the linked implementation contains an error in that ASCII `0` is transformed into hexadecimal byte `0x00`.

Answer (score 4):

[Project Nayuki](https://www.nayuki.io/page/aes-cipher-internals-in-excel) has an [Excel sheet](https://www.nayuki.io/page/aes-cipher-internals-in-excel) in binary, XML and OpenDocument format. The code doesn't include any  Vusial Basic or Macros, they used only the spreadsheet's math functions; `VLOOKUP`, `BITXOR`, `DEC2HEX`, and `HEX2DEC`.

They have also, a nice video for AES on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mlzxpkdXP58) and a [flash animation](https://web.archive.org/web/20051124061027/http://www.cs.bc.edu/~straubin/cs381-05/blockciphers/rijndael_ingles2004.swf) if you can run somewhere.